# How to sketch and determine direction of streamline functions?

Tags: vectors, graphing-functions, fluid-dynamics

In my fluid dynamics course, I am required to know how to sketch streamlines and showing their direction like two examples below. The only method I know is by plotting through using  a table with values of $x$ and $y$. Is there a better method? and is there a textbook or some other material that shows how to do this? Also, how to determine the direction of the streamline? Why is the plot for $\psi=0$ in the first plot seems to be in the opposite direction to the plot for $\psi=0$ in the second plot.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what is the given data and what is asked to you ? To draw one exact stream line ? besides, what do you call "using a table". Is it with a spreadsheet ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, I want to draw each equation from $\psi=0,1,2,...$. In particular, I am confused why the direction of the plot differs for $\psi=0$ even though the equations the same?

Comment: @JeanMarie, I mean why is the red line in the first plot is going in the opposite direction to the blue streamlines?

Comment: For the first graphical representation, compute the speeds $(\partial \psi/\partial x, \partial \psi/\partial y)$ in some points you will see that these vectors "flow" in opposite directions to those you have depicted (they are are ill-oriented) : this is what is advised in the answers to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2707374/305862)